# Asynchronous dispatch resource hog in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, user-interface, asynchronous

I am fairly new to the Swift programming language, making GUIs, and to using asynchronous dispatches in general, so please forgive this question which — I'd imagine — has an excruciatingly simple answer.

What I am attempting to do is to disable and re-enable the `Next` button in the GUI based on whether or not valid settings have been selected. These settings are found in two checkboxes and a text field.

My idea was to have a process in the background continually checking the settings and — if valid — enable the `Next` button. This code block is my most recent attempt:

```
func checkValidSettings() {
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        while true {
            if self.textField.stringValue == "Test" {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.nextButton.enabled = false
                }
            } else if (self.checkBox1.state == NSOffState && self.checkBox2.state == NSOffState){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.nextButton.enabled = false
                }
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.nextButton.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though this runs correctly, it causes the application to be a huge resource hog (100% CPU and several GBs of memory), which I assume to be because a ton of background tasks are being created. I messed up somewhere pretty badly, haha.

My question is this: how should I structure the `while` loop so that it continually checks the settings while not commandeering all of my resources? Or is there a simpler way of GUI management?

Thanks in advance for any advice or help you can give!

Comment: Why loop? Just check the conditions when value changed. you can register callback for it. also your code is _not_ thread-safe. You _can't_ access UI element from non-main thread.

Comment: You know, that makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do, haha. How do I check the conditions when the value has changed?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/textDidChange:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS you don't have to create your own listeners. You can simply assign an IBAction and some bools.

```
@IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!

var fieldCheck1: Bool = false
var fieldCheck2: Bool = false

@IBAction func field1Changed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if field1.text == "true statement" {
        fieldCheck1 = true
    }
    self.checkComplete()
}


@IBAction func field2Changed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if field2.text == "true statement" {
        fieldCheck2 = true
    }
    self.checkComplete()
}

func checkComplete() {
    if fieldCheck1 == true && fieldCheck2 == true{
        // enable your Next Button
    }
}
```

If it interests you, you can also use monitored properties to check if the property itself changed value and run code based off that:

```
var myBool: Bool = false {
     willSet(newValue) {
          if newValue == true {
                // Run some code now that the bool is true
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example! That's a lot simpler than what I had in mind. Though I have this tagged OS X, your example is definitely general-use enough that I can utilize it. Thanks again!

Comment: Anytime! The methods themselves, like `@IBAction func field2Changed` are auto generated when you control-drag a text field from the interface builder into the Swift file and change `outlet` to `action`, so if it's different on OS X, it will change accordingly! Regardless, the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are wasting CPU because you have a `while true` loop on a background thread that doesn't do very much inside the loop (so it just spins) and, of course, because you're enqueueing lots of work onto the main thread as well.

You'll want to use the [target/action mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000073-SW16) to listen for callbacks when the control values change, and only change `enabled` when necessary. There's no need to use a background queue/thread for this work, since it'll be very fast. The key is to do it only when necessary.

You can also look into using [bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) to automatically change the `enabled` state.

And this is even more advanced, so I hesitate to mention it, but you may want to consider [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa), as it makes simple form validation like this very easy.

Comment: Though I didn't mark your response as the answer, you've given me a few good resources for my future projects. Thanks for taking time out of your day to help!